# Using jQuery to delay loading of divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to delay loading a row of divs until scrolls, sort of like this [codepen](http://codepen.io/Afiq/pen/IoFkz). I can't seem to get any of my jquery to fire for some reason.

**jQuery / JS**

```
// lazy load
$(".resource-container resume-row").slice(1).hide();

 var mincount = 0;
 var maxcount = 1;


 $(window).scroll(function () {
     if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() - 50) {
         $(".resource-container .resume-row").slice(mincount, maxcount).slideDown(100);

         mincount = mincount + 0;
         maxcount = maxcount + 5;
         //Loads 1 variable at a time 

     }
 });
```

Here is my attempt so far: [my codepen](http://codepen.io/TyStelmach/pen/MYdmpO). I would like to ultimately load 3/4(and so on) rows and then have the 4th row come in 1 at a time.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: An infinite scrolling/lazy loading plugin is probably what you want, so you don't have to re-invent tohe wheel and handle all the edge cases: http://jscroll.com/

Comment: I would use LazyLoadXT, but am constrained as it is being built on to Hubspot's COS/CMS. The items can't be contained in an array as they would if I were to build it in angular or use LazyLoad.

Comment: I see you fixed the selector, but now you notice that your scroll event doesn't fire because you can't scroll? give your `body` a `height` that overflows so that scrolling is possible, something like `body{height:1000px}`

Comment: I just down sized my browser so they stacked 1x1 to test haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the classname denotation (.) in your first selector for the classname "resume-row"

```
// lazy load
$(".resource-container .resume-row").slice(1).hide();

 var mincount = 0;
 var maxcount = 1;


 $(window).scroll(function () {
     if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() - 50) {
         $(".resource-container .resource-row").slice(mincount, maxcount).slideDown(100);

         mincount = mincount + 0;
         maxcount = maxcount + 5;
         //Loads 1 variable at a time 

     }
 });
```

Comment: Odd how you miss these sort of things. Long story short, the code is now correct and working on codepen, so this was technically the solution. For some reason it doesn't want to fire off in Hubspot's COS/CMS. So i'm on tech support with them now, thanks for the help haha

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea of how to slow certain divs
http://jsfiddle.net/mronyrcv/1/

I get the number of divs and assign them all a data-row attribute that keeps the number div they are. I then use the modulus operator " % " to determine if they can be divided by 4. Modulus gives you a remainder which is why it's better than straight division in situations where you're number of elements can change. a.e. if you need to limit number of elements on a page. I attached the event to show them to a button. The code states that if the number remaining is 0 after the data-row % 4 formula is performed, then use the .delay() method to prevent fadeToggle from firing for 900ms, if there IS a remainder it will still use the .delay() method but only for 500ms.

```
var i;
for(i=1; i < ($("div").length +1);i++) {
$("div").eq(i-1).attr("data-row", i);
}

$("#showthese").on("click", function() {

var resources = $("div").length; 
for(i=0; i < resources;i++) {
    if ($("div").eq(i).attr("data-row") % 4 === 0) {
        $("div").eq(i).delay(900).fadeToggle();
  }
    else {
        $("div").eq(i).delay(500).fadeToggle();
  }
 }
});
```

That's the concept. You can replace fadeToggle with any animation.